# What are the options for making information on an Android phone available to a tethered machine?

Tags: android

End goal: be able to see what level and type of cell connectivity my phone currently has on the laptop that is tethered to the phone (e.g. 4g:two bars, 3g:4 bars, etc.).

I don't really care how I achieve this.  My first thought was either a server on the laptop that the phone pings every X seconds or vice versa, but since my knowledge of Android development is next to zero, I figured it was worth finding out what my options were.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the connection status and changes in connectivity you may need the [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html).

To publish the information obtained you may use a web container like [i-jetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/) that you can ping from your laptop.